# Simple way to monitor a multiple URLDownloadSubmit calls?

Tags: asynchronous-processing, url

I have a list of download jobs (e.g. `{{url, filename} ...}`) to do:

```
jobs = Table[{"https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random", 
              "~/Downloads/" <> ToString[i] <> ".jpg"}, {i, 5}]
```

Clearly the `ProgressIndicator` here does not show the percent completion of the asynchronous tasks:

```
Monitor[Table[URLDownloadSubmit @@ jobs[[i]], {i, 5}], 
        ProgressIndicator[Dynamic[i], {0, 5}]]
```

So I'm looking for a nice way to monitor the total progress of all tasks created in a call like this:

```
Scan[URLDownloadSubmit@@#&, jobs]
```

without resorting to the obsolete symbols `URLFetchAsynchronous` and `URLSaveAsynchronous`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is an example of how to build a download manager.

We start by defining a function that uses `URLDownloadSubmit` to initiate a download:

```
manifest = <||>;

SetAttributes[taskProgress, HoldFirst]
taskProgress[manifest_][event_] := 
 manifest = <|manifest, event["Task"] -> event|>

SetAttributes[taskFinished, HoldFirst]
taskFinished[manifest_][event_] := 
 manifest = <|manifest, event["Task"] -> event|>

SetAttributes[startJob, HoldFirst]
startJob[manifest_][src_, dest_] := URLDownloadSubmit[
   src, dest,
   HandlerFunctions -> <|
     "ConnectionFailed" -> connectionFailed[manifest],
     "CookiesReceived" -> cookiesReceived[manifest],
     "HeadersReceived" -> headersReceived[manifest],
     "TaskFinished" -> taskFinished[manifest],
     "TaskProgress" -> taskProgress[manifest],
     "TaskStatusChanged" -> taskStatusChanged[manifest]
     |>,
   HandlerFunctionsKeys -> {
     "Task", "TaskStatus", "File",
     "ByteCountTotal", "ByteCountDownloaded", "FractionComplete"
     }
   ];
```

We have defined a variable, `manifest`, that will hold information about the files being downloaded. It is up to the user to define the event handler functions that they want to use; in my download manager, I will only use `TaskProgress` and `TaskFinished`. Whenever any of those events are called, I update `manifest` with the latest information. The latest information includes the variables specified under `HandleFunctionsKeys`.

This is all we need, really. Now we can build an interface to visualize `manifest`.

```
SetAttributes[abortDownload, HoldFirst]
abortDownload[manifest_, task_] := (
  TaskRemove /@ Select[Tasks[], #["TaskUUID"] === task["TaskUUID"] &];
  manifest = <|
    manifest,
    task -> <|manifest[task], "TaskStatus" -> "Aborted"|>
    |>)

SetAttributes[visualizeManifest, HoldFirst]
visualizeManifest[manifest_] := TableForm[Join[
   {{"File", "Size (MB)", "Downloaded (MB)", "Fraction complete", 
     "Status", ""}}, {
      #File
      , Floor[#ByteCountTotal/10^6]
      , Floor[#ByteCountDownloaded/10^6]
      , ProgressIndicator[#FractionComplete]
      , #TaskStatus
      , Button["Abort", abortDownload[manifest, #Task], 
       Enabled -> (#TaskStatus =!= "Aborted")]
      } & /@ Values[manifest]
   ]]
```

I will also add a button to begin downloading an Anaconda installer. Anaconda is a software for Python programmers that I picked because the installer is large enough in size that the download won't finish in a blip.

```
i = 0;
Button["Download", startJob[manifest][
  "https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-5.2.0-MacOSX-x86_64.pkg",
  "~/Downloads/anaconda" <> ToString[i++] <> ".pkg"
  ]]

Dynamic@visualizeManifest[manifest]
```

The final result looks like this:

[image]

You can easily compute other statistics such as how many of the files have finished downloading by going through the values in the `manifest` association.

Comment: I would like to use this for monitoring multiple thousand image downloads without having to hard code the `ToString[i++] <> ".ext"`... is there some way of doing this?

Comment: @M.R. I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean. There is nothing in the code that I can see that requires hard-coding...

Answer (score 6):

Here's another way to do this, based on extracting the `"File"` handler key

```
parallelDownload[things_] :=
 DynamicModule[
  {jobs, results},
  Dynamic[
   Internal`LoadingPanel@
    Grid@
     If[AllTrue[Values@results, # =!= None &],
       Append[
        {
         Button[
          "Get Result",
          NotebookWrite[
           Nest[ParentBox, EvaluationBox[], 5],
           ToBoxes@Values@results
           ]
          ],
         SpanFromLeft
         }
        ],
       Identity
       ]@
      KeyValueMap[
       {
         Row@{#[[1]], ":"},
          If[#2 =!= None, "Complete", "Waiting..."]
         } &,
       results
       ]
   ],
  Initialization :>
   {
    results = <||>,
    jobs = <||>,
    Map[
     With[{job = Flatten[{#}]},
       results[job] = None;
       jobs[job] =
        URLDownloadSubmit[
         Sequence @@ job, 
         HandlerFunctions ->
          <|"TaskFinished" :> Function[results[job] = #File]|>,
         HandlerFunctionsKeys -> {"File"}
         ]
       ] &,
     things
     ]
    }
  ]
```

If we run that on the jobs it pops a little watching interface:

[image]

After that's done it shows a button to replace the box with the result:

[image]

And pressing the button gives us the desired result:

```
{
 "~/Downloads/1.jpg", "~/Downloads/2.jpg", 
 "~/Downloads/3.jpg", "~/Downloads/4.jpg", 
 "~/Downloads/5.jpg"
 }
```

#### With ProgressIndicator

Here's an alternate interface for many files

```
parallelDownloadDynamic[
  things_, 
  var:Dynamic[_]|None:None,
  e:OptionsPattern[Dynamic]
  ] :=
 DynamicModule[
  {jobs, results},
  Dynamic[
   Replace[var,
     Verbatim[Dynamic][s_]:>(Set[s, results])
     ];
   If[AllTrue[Values@results, # =!= None &],
     Button[
        "Get Result",
        NotebookWrite[
           Nest[ParentBox, EvaluationBox[], 1],
           ToBoxes@Values@results
           ]
        ],
     Internal`LoadingPanel@ProgressIndicator[
       Count[Values[results], Except[None]],
       {0, Length[results]}
       ]
     ],
   e
   ],
  Initialization :>
   {
    results = <||>,
    jobs = <||>,
    Map[
     With[{job = Flatten[{#}]},
       results[job] = None;
       jobs[job] =
        URLDownloadSubmit[
         Sequence @@ job, 
         HandlerFunctions ->
          <|"TaskFinished" :> Function[results[job] = Replace[#["File"], Except[_String]->$Failed]]|>,
         HandlerFunctionsKeys -> {"File"}
         ]
       ] &,
     things
     ]
    }
  ]
```

Comment: I always wonder why functions like ``Internal`LoadingPanel`` are not in the supported language.  (+1)

Comment: @Edmund I'd almost rather they not be... the ``"System`"`` context is bloated enough as is. Why they have to be in ``"Internal`"`` though is beyond me. Some 
 type of supported ``"Formatting`"`` context would be perfect for it. Or even better, some context that makes it clear that there's a front-end kernel separation. Unfortunately we're too far past the point of no-return for that.

Comment: @b3m2a1 THis looks like it could work, but not thousands of URLs... Can you try changing into a progress bar and letting the File name come from the url/header?

Comment: @M.R. try the edit

Answer (score 5):

You may use the [`HandlerFunctions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HandlerFunctions.html) option of [`URLDownloadSubmit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/URLDownloadSubmit.html) to track a counter updated in `"TaskFinished"` event.

With `jobs` as defined in OP.

```
completedCount = 0;
tasks =
  URLDownloadSubmit[#1, #2,
     HandlerFunctions -> <|"TaskFinished" -> (completedCount++ &)|>
     ] & @@@ jobs;
ProgressIndicator[Dynamic[completedCount], {0, Length@tasks}]
```

This outputs a [`ProgressIndicator`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ProgressIndicator.html) that tracks the completion of the tasks.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Here I create a different list of *asynchronous tasks* , but should be the same with your downloads.

```
tasklist = 
  Table[SessionSubmit[ScheduledTask[counter += 1, {m}]], {m, 1, 20}];

Dynamic[
 ProgressIndicator[
  Count[Through@tasklist["TaskStatus"], "Removed"]
  , {0, Length[tasklist]}
  ], UpdateInterval -> 1]
```

[image]

Comment: this has nothing to do with parallel downloading

Comment: @user5601 Easy with the down votes, the request was for a *"way to monitor the total progress of all tasks created"*, except for CE's answer that went further measuring file sizes, a general solutions for arbitrary asynchronous tasks applies in particular for asynchronous download tasks.