# How to build a file download manager?

Tags: resource-management

I want to build something like `ResourceData` to distributing neural network models and paclets.

This system preferably has the following three features.

- It's lazy.

Lazy means it will not load unless you call it.

`var := var = Import["path"]` will not load until call `var`.

- It's asynchronous.

Asynchronous means it does not prevent you from doing other things when loading or downloading.

`ResourceData` is not asynchronous. `URLDownloadSubmit` is asynchronous when downloading.

- It's has a progress bar.

This is not necessary, but it should at least remind you that the download or load is complete.

`` GeneralUtilities`ProgressPanel["Downloading...","something",0.5] ``, this may helpful but not mult-files available.

---

#### Some Thoughts

1. `ResourceData` is not asynchronous, because it must return a certain result, the loading is completed or `$Failed`.

So an asynchronous loading system can return `Missing[]` when it has not finished loading. Then we can use `If[MissingQ@var,Return[]]` to do further processing.

2. A possible method of capturing assignment variables

`f /: Set[x_, f[y__]] := doSomething[x,y];`

then try `var = f["file","url"]`, this may useful.

Comment: Did you see [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/177199/731)?